# How to prove Gauss map is differentiable?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, surfaces

I am studying differential geometry with do carmo's book. In his book, on page 136, the definition of the Gauss map is given,
[image: Definition of the Gauss map]

He then proceeds to say it's straightforward to verify the Gauss map is differentiable. Actually, I have no idea how to prove this, can someone help me understand why?
Any explanation will be very welcome.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! <> Given a smooth parametrization of a surface, we can _write down_ the Gauss mapping and see it's smooth in local coordinates.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the following: What hypotheses do we have on the smoothness of the surface? What is the actual formula for the Gauss map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this depends on the smoothness of $S$. We need $S$ to be at least $C^2$.
Locally, say $S$ is parametrized by $x(u,v), y(u,v), z(u,v)$. Then we have two tangent vectors $T_u = (x_u, y_u, z_u)$ and $T_v = (x_v, y_v, z_v)$ everywhere. The normal vector is $T_u\times T_v$ (or $-T_u\times T_v$ which depends on the orientation). This needs to be normalized to be $$N(u,v)=\frac{T_u\times T_v}{\|T_u\times T_v\|}$$

Now to show $N$ is differentiable, note that $N_u, N_v$ only depends on $T_u, T_v, T_{uu},T_{uv}, T_{vv}$, and since $T$ is $C^2$, we know $N_u, N_v$ are continuous and hence $N$ is at least $C^1$.

However, I would suggest not to worry too much about smoothness as a beginner. You may assume everything is $C^{\infty}$ and gain the key geometric intution first.

Comment: Thank you for sharing, I learned a lot.